# Rearranging viewControllers in self.navigationController.viewControllers is not working obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Say, In my `self.navigationController.viewControllers` I have `n` number of `viewControllers`. Within them, I only want to remain 2 `viewControllers` in my `self.navigationController.viewControllers`. One is at `0 index` & another one is at `1 index`. Here is my code.

```
        NSMutableArray *VCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
        NSMutableArray *savedVCsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i = 0; i < [VCs count]; i++) {
            UIViewController *vc = VCs[i];
            if ([vc isKindOfClass:[LanguageSettingsViewController class]]) {
                [savedVCsArray insertObject:vc atIndex:0];
            } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[SignInViewController class]]) {
                [savedVCsArray insertObject:vc atIndex:1];
            }
        }

        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:savedVCsArray];
        NSLog(@"counts %i", [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]);
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

But, here I always get `NSLog(@"counts %i", [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]);` 0. Is there I am missing something? Thanks in advance. Glad if you reply.

**xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)**
**iOS 10.3**

Comment: What's the value of `self.navigationController`?  (i.e. Is it non-nil?)

Comment: It is a pointer type value `0x00000000`, nope, it is not nill.

Comment: So, in other words, it looks like the `self` object in your code doesn't have a `navigationController`.  Did you check what was in the `VCs` array?

Comment: 0x00000000 is a LOT like nil.  :)

Comment: Oh, ok. Yes, before insertValue it has all viewControllers list. Like this : 

<LanguageSettingsViewController: 0x78f8cbc0>
<SignInViewController: 0x7a0c9a00>
<SWRevealViewController: 0x7aa83600>

Comment: And savedVCsArray has this two as I want <LanguageSettingsViewController: 0x78f8cbc0>,
<SignInViewController: 0x7a0c9a00>
But some how strangely this line of code is not seems working [self.navigationController setViewControllers:savedVCsArray]; :(

Comment: Ignore *"counts 0"* for the moment... If you comment out the `popToViewController` line, do you get the results you want?

Comment: Actually what I want here, is that try to put that two viewController in the navigationController stack and `popToViewController` in one of them which is `SignInViewController`. I can't ignore it.

Comment: @DonMag after `popToViewController` In my `SignInViewController`, I am getting correct `viewController` list in my `navigatoinController` stack. :O.
It seems like working, though the count is showing 0 after inserting state. :/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you confirm that you actually *have* the VCs you want:

```
UIViewController *langVC = nil;
UIViewController *signVC = nil;

for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[LanguageSettingsViewController class]]) {
        // [savedVCsArray insertObject:vc atIndex:0];
        langVC = vc;
    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[SignInViewController class]]) {
        // [savedVCsArray insertObject:vc atIndex:1];
        signVC = vc;
    }
}

if (langVC == nil || signVC == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Problem exists because langVC is %@ / signVC is %@", langVC, signVC);

} else {

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[langVC, signVC] animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have also tried with your code, but it always print **0** for `NSLog(@"counts %i", [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]);` after inserting state. But in my `SignInViewController` when I print the `[self.navigationController.viewControllers count]`, it is gave me required count which is 2. So I don't think there is any problem in code, rather it may have some other issue.

Comment: Ah - well, when you call `.setViewControllers` the transition is async. So, when you immediately check the count, it appears that (internally) the Navigation Controller has already cleared the Stack but has not yet added the new array of VCs. If you check the count *after* the transition is completed, you should see the correct value.

Comment: Ohh! So all this for `async` transition. :)) Thanks a lot for informing the details. I was little bit confused at it. Have a nice day mate. :)